# Adding a column with partition in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula

I am new to PowerBI and not familiar with DAX expression/M language

I got the below table

| BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | BaggageID | SSRCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 | 074 | 851 | 399 | WCI |
| 534 | 076 | 852 | 400 | WCI |
| 030 | 789 | 744 | 435 | PB20 |
| 030 | 789 | 744 | null | MCI |
| 369 | 263 | 439 | 428 | BULK |
| 369 | 263 | 439 | 427 | BULK |

And I want to add 2 columns, MCI_Flag & WCI_Flag, below is the logic:

1. Partitioned by SegmentID
2. In those partitioned SegmentID, check which SSRCode are in there. If there are MCI/WCI, then mark MCI_Flag/WCI_Flag as 1 otherwise 0

For example, SegmentID = 37722789, it gets SSRCode, PB20 and MCI. Since there is MCI, so MCI_Flag for these 2 rows is 1

To be precise, the expected result

| BookingID | SegmentID | PassengerID | BaggageID | SSRCode | MCI_Flag | WCI_Flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 534 | 074 | 851 | 399 | WCI | 0 | 1 |
| 534 | 076 | 852 | 400 | WCI | 0 | 1 |
| 030 | 789 | 744 | 435 | PB20 | 1 | 0 |
| 030 | 789 | 744 | null | MCI | 1 | 0 |
| 369 | 263 | 439 | 428 | BULK | 0 | 0 |
| 369 | 263 | 439 | 427 | BULK | 0 | 0 |

Could anyone give a help?

Comment: Not clear how Partition has anything to do with the flags... isn't it just a conditional column? Like this in DAX? MCI_Flag = IF(MCI_Flag in {"MCI","PBI20"},1,0) and WCI_Flag = IF(WCI_Flag="WCI",1,0)

Answer (score 0):

Like @mxix mentioned, it is more a calculated conditional column :

```
MCI_Flag = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(MyTable),
        FILTER(
            ALL(MyTable),
            MyTable[SegmentID] = EARLIER(MyTable[SegmentID]) && MyTable[SSRCode] = "MCI"
        )
    ) > 0,
    1,
    0
)
MCI_Flag = 
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS(MyTable),
        FILTER(
            ALL(MyTable),
            MyTable[SegmentID] = EARLIER(MyTable[SegmentID]) && MyTable[SSRCode] = "MCI"
        )
    ) > 0,
    1,
    0
)
```

You need to calculate for each row, whether there exists at least one row with the same SegmentID and the specified SSRCode (MCI or WCI).
The FILTER functionwill help you to consider all rows in the context of the calculation (ALL(MyTable)) but only for rows matching the current row's SegmentID.

Then comes EARLIER to reference the SegmentID from the outer row context. If at least one row meets the criteria, COUNTROWS will return a number greater than 0, resulting in the IF condition being true and setting the flag to 1otherwise, it's set to 0.